# Method generic type specialization with where in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, where-clause, equatable

I am working with generics and I would like to compare objects to optimize some operations. I have a base "abstract" class that is then specialized with String, Int... or more generic types like Any or [Any]. I had a first implementation where a comparison method was always returning "different" and was override in Equatable subclasses, but:

- a bunch of code was duplicated;
- the subclass managing "Any" was always returning "different", even if the actual objects were actually Equatable.

I am therefore trying to regroup the code in my abstract class, but I am struggling with the constraints on Equatable and the only compiling solution I came up with is method `where` specialization. However, the result is not the one I expected: it looks like the method is chosen at compilation time rather than at runtime, so it would not solve my problem.

```swift
class MyGeneric<T: Any> {

    func test() {
        print(method(to: nil))
    }
    func test1() {
        print(method(to: nil))
    }

    func method(to newValue: T?) -> String {
        "Not equatable"
    }

    func method(to newValue: T?) -> String where T: Equatable {
        "Equatable"
    }
}

class MyString: MyGeneric<String> {

    override func test1() {
        print(method(to: nil))
    }
}

MyString().test() // Not equatable, since T is String at runtime I would like to have Equatable here
MyString().test1() // Equatable
```

Am I completely in the wrong direction? Is there a way to have an equality check on objects that are not equatable by default, with a result as "different" by default? Like:

```swift
func isDifferent(a: T?: b: T?) -> Bool {
   if let a = a as? Equatable, let b = b as? Equatable { // Doesn't compile 
      return a != b
   } else {
      return true
   }
}
```

I have found quite a lot of old topics offering some solutions that do not compile anymore, or mention that it is not *yet* available in the language. I am hoping here that a new solution was found.

Comment: You're almost certainly moving in the wrong direction. `Any` is not generic, and is actively fighting your other code. Also, class inheritance is not a good foundation for building this kind of system. Focus first on what kind of code will *call* this type, and what kinds of algorithms you're trying to build that lead to duplicate code. And we can use that to help you design a correct generic solution, which will likely be a struct or `final` class (usually a struct), and a protocol. But the most important thing is to get rid of `Any` in this code. That's almost impossible to work with well.

Comment: @RobNapier I am doing a wrapper on top of the keychain, to be able to store safely data as easily as in the UserDefaults. I am storing Codable objects as Data and sending an event whenever a value is changed.
My specific goal here is to check if the new set value is to check if the current value is equal to the new one, so I can prevent the event from being fired an all the code listening to this event from being executed.

Comment: @RobNapier 
The point is I am doing a framework that is used in other frameworks that I am not developing myself. So I am trying to find the right balance between keeping the API as open as possible and offering some optimizations and features around it.
I added the Codable constraint, I wanted to add the Equatable one but it seems to be impossible. My next thought would be the NSObject contraint, but I am not sure  either about all the issues I would need to cover if I try to encode mixed NSObjects with collections, etc.

Comment: So you definitely don't mean `Any`, since you can't store `Any` in Keychain. Codable sounds good, but why is Equatable not possible for you as a constraint on the store function? (Moreover, it seems in that case very easy to have two store functions, one for Equatable and one for not, if checking equality is just an optimization.) Maybe showing your intended API here would help. `Any` is absolutely not the right tool, though.

Comment: I use the following DataStore for storing values in UserDefaults. A similar thing could be the basis for Keychain. (I realize it does not have all the features you're describing, but it may be a useful starting point.) https://gist.github.com/rnapier/f7f0fa6202b0d6586af188635f54b28b

Answer (score 2):

You might be overthinking this if all you want is your `isDifferent` function; simple overloading is sufficient:

```
func isDifferent<T: Equatable>(_ a: T, _ b: T) -> Bool { a != b }
func isDifferent(_ a: Any, _ b: Any) -> Bool { true }

struct S {
    let name: String
}
struct SEquatable: Equatable {
    let name: String
}

isDifferent(S(name:"hello"), S(name:"hello")) // true
isDifferent(SEquatable(name:"hello"), SEquatable(name:"hello")) // false
isDifferent(SEquatable(name:"hello"), SEquatable(name:"goodbye")) // true
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue. I want the code to be generic and present only at one place in my class class `MyGeneric<T: Any>`.
I tried why what you suggested, since in the generic class the exact type is not known, the method with `Any` is always called, the `Equatable` one never.

Comment: Oh, I understand that. There are important qualifiers in my answer, as you may observe. But since overall you're asking to do something meaningless and impossible, I picked up on just your last paragraph and showed you something you _can_ do. _My_ method with Any _is_ called precisely when the parameter type is not Equatable, and thus we get the "right" answer, as I've proved. Whether you choose to adapt your desires to the realm of the possible is up to you, of course.

Comment: If the answer is "No, it is still not possible to achieve that in Swift", let's answer that and stay in "the realm of the possible". Reworking my code to put it outside a class doesn't help much.